# Alfresco custom aikau footer

Tags: dojo, alfresco, alfresco-share, aikau

I want to customize Alfresco aikau footer. For the beginning I would like to inject custom html-template in AlfShareFooter. So far I created an extension:

```
<extension>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>MyCmpny widgets</id>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
      <configurations>
        <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="WebFramework" replace="false">
          <web-framework>
            <dojo-pages>
              <packages>
                <package name="mycmpny" location="js/mycmpny"/>
              </packages>
            </dojo-pages>
          </web-framework>
        </config>
      </configurations>
    </module>
  </modules>
</extension>
```

Html template for the footer and now I'm trying to override `templateString` of the AlfShareFooter object:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "alfresco/footer/AlfShareFooter'",
        "dojo/text!./templates/ep-footer.html"],
       function (declare, AlfShareFooter, template) {
         return declare([AlfShareFooter], {
           templateString: template
         })
       });
```

But it doesn't work. I am not familiar with Dojo and I think the problem is in the syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out how to override template:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/text!./templates/my-footer.html",
    "alfresco/footer/AlfShareFooter"],
    function (declare, template, AlfShareFooter) {
      return declare([AlfShareFooter],{
        postMixInProperties: function my_footer_AlfShareFooter__postMixInProperties(){
          this.inherited(arguments);
          this.templateString = template;
        }
      });
    });
```

But with g̶r̶e̶a̶t̶ custom footer template comes g̶r̶e̶a̶t̶ custom css and i18n... So I wrote a [post](http://pavelmakhov.com/2016/02/customize-alfresco-footer-aikau) about changing Aikau footer in Alfresco.

Comment: There's currently a 404 error when trying to access your post. It would be interesting to read if you could make it available.